# accessing elements of an array causing my app to crash

Tags: javascript, xml, image, syntax, null

Ok, really basic quetion. I'm just not getting this. I am parsing an xml feed. I am searching inside a tag for a regular expression of an image. At the minute, when I print

`str.match(patt1)`
, 
I am getting:

`http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/jimmy.jpg,http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/jimmy.jpg,jpg`

in the console. I just need the first element i.e.

`http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/jimmy.jpg`

To do this I tried str.match(patt1)[0] but this line is causing my app to crash. I am setting this varibale to equal a leftImage propert of a table row. I am also testing if it is null to 'continue' with the loop as I thought that may have been the problem.

I also tried str.match(patt1[0]) but this si not giving me the desired output either.  What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: APP JS BELOW:

```
    var win1 = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff',
    //tabBarHidden: true

});
var tab = Titanium.UI.createTab({  
    icon:'KS_nav_views.png',
    title:'Tab 1',
    window:win1
});

var data = [];

var table = Ti.UI.createTableView({
    //data:data
});

var url="http://www.highlandradio.com/feed/"; 
//rss feed url
//var url="http://apod.nasa.gov/apod.rss"; //  rss feed url
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();

xhr.onload = function() {
    // Data is returned from the blog, start parsing
    var doc = this.responseXML.documentElement;

    // begin looping through blog posts
    var items = doc.getElementsByTagName("item");
    console.log(items);
    for (var i=0;i<items.length;i++) {

        var str=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("content:encoded").item(0).text;
        console.log("FIRST STRING TEST "+ str);
        //var src= items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("content:encoded").item(0).getAttribute("src");
        //console.log("FIRST SRC TEST "+ src);
        var patt1=/([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i;


        var urlMatch = str.match(patt1);
        data.push({

            title: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("title").item(0).text,            
            leftImage: urlMatch.length > 0 ? urlMatch[0] : 'NewsStory.png',
            dataToPass: items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("description").item(0).text,
            className: "TableRow", 
            hasChild: true, 
            jsTest: true,
            js:"external.js"
        });

    }

    table.setData(data);

};

xhr.onerror = function(e) {
    // should do something more robust
    alert('Network error '+e.error);
};

xhr.open('GET',url);
xhr.send();

win1.add(table);


win1.open();
```

Comment: Can you define what "crash" means?

Comment: @Ray Nicholas by crash I mean, the app stays on the splash screen and the line str.match(patt1)[0] is highlighted blue and I am told to debug that line

Answer (score 0):

You can user array access to function result of match(), as:

```
// Prints 1st element of str.match(patt1) to console   
console.log(str.match(patt1)[0]);
```

But if you will use matches in future you should put result array to variable and work with it.

Comment: Try i.e. this:
`var matches = str.match(patt1);
console.log(matches[0]);`

Comment: still causing the app to crash. I don't get it

Comment: as in that line is being highlighted in blue and I am being told to debug. the log is extremely long.. I am using titanium and just running any basic app with it produces an extremely long log. Shall I post it here?

Comment: That's will be better than nothing)

Comment: Ok right now I am trying to cater for if the match is null but it's based on the same principle as yours and I'm getting the blue highlighted line error in the same place as with you. My app.js is as follows fyi:.

Comment: if I include the log I am exceeding the max characters allowed

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixe with this line:

```
`leftImage: str.match(patt1) !== null ? str.match(patt1)[0] : 'NewsStory.png',
```

I forgot match returns an object when there are no results rather than undefined.